# Adding Skills in search Refinement Panel displays GUID along with actual values

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, people-search, refinement-panel

I need to add `Skills` as a part of the Refinement panel and so I have used `RefinableString100` pointed to `ows_taxId_SPShSkills` that stored the users skills.

The refiner is added but along with the skills it also brings up the GUID of the terms.

I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this question is --> Create a custom managed property utilizing either of the `RefinableString` properties available OOTB and map them to `People:SPS-Skills`, add an **ALIAS** -

> 'Skills'

and you are good to go.

Adding the **ALIAS** did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For a managed metadata field there are usually two fields. One holding the complete (term) information including the id's etc. And one with only the 'text value'.

Look if you have a managed property called `ows_SPShSkills`  (without the 'taxid'). And use that field as a refiner. It will hold the textual value of the managed metadata.

If that managed property is not present you can create it and attach the correct crawled property (without the 'taxid') to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to find this property.

Answer (score 1):

Skills comes from the People Profile. Try using the Managed Property "Skills" which is mapped to People:SPS-Skills.

"ows_" is a list column prefix.

Comment: Did you define a new Managed Property or use the Out of the box property?

Comment: That's likely the problem. If you don't define the property in the SSA it won't work. Just use the Out of the Box property "Skills". Or if you must define your own, do it in the Search Service App not in a site.

Comment: Let me know. Please mark as answer if it works for you.